# How to Remove "Throw new System.NotImplementedException()" lane, when implement an interface in Rider?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rider

I use the `Jet Brains Rider` compiler and I want to remove the default lane related to implement. Because in some implementations, the number of methods is large and if they are not deleted, they give an error in `Unity`. If you know the address of this setting, please help.

```cs
public class CharacterA : MonoBehaviour, ICharacterController
{
    public void UpdateRotation(ref Quaternion currentRotation, float deltaTime)
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException(); // <=== remove this lane from default setting
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure it's possible to prevent that line being added but, if it is possible, you shouldn't change it anyway. The whole point of that line is to prevent you from accidentally failing to implement a method. Without it, you won't be warned that a method wasn't implemented so you might overlook implementing it, which would be bad. You can always do a Find & Replace to change it to write a message to the Console or the like.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to change this, but as @jmcilhinney mentioned, you don't want to. This doesn't result in a compilation error, and you definitely want to know at runtime if something that hasn't been implemented has been called on an interface implementation. If you're adamant that it shouldn't result in an exception, then replace the default implementation with some form of logging telling you that this occurred (at the least). Or just go ahead and delete the `throw new [...]` part and hope for the best.

Comment: Actually, it is possible to do so, contrarily to Visual Studio where you could access that through the options button at the bottom of the wizard, for Rider you have to do that through the settings instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The option that you are looking for is in *Editor > Members Generation*:

[image]

Use *Return default value* instead to solve your problem.